# mongo query greater than last value

Tags: mongodb, find

say I have a collection:
speed: 40
speed: 43
speed: 78
speed: 90
speed: 22

and I want to query to find when the speed values change more than 10 miles an hour faster or slower.  Can that be built in to a mongo query or is it time for javascript to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do it with a mongo query.  This query would require to look at two documents at a time - which as far as I know is not possible today and might not be possible to implement efficiently ever (because if you use sharding the documents of a single collection might be distributed across different machines).

This looks complicated to achieve even in SQL - maybe it can achieved using a self join.

If you find something difficult to query it might be an indication that your model is not right.  It would be good idea to investigate if a different way of modeling the schema, before jumping to do it using javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the modeling schema, makes sense.